# Visualforce page not rendering values from controller

Tags: salesforce, visualforce

Need your inputs in a scenario I am currently stuck in. Here are the details. Appreciate your time and all your inputs.

- currently I am able to see the values retrieved in controller but they are not being displayed on visualforce page.

Requirement: I need to email bulk of selected contacts. When there is no email to selected contacts, we are required to populate the name of contacts on UI who do not have the email.  I am able to accomplish first part of requirement but stuck on displaying contact names on visual force page .

1. List button : BulkEmailTest which calls firstVF visual force page.
2. firstVF code:

   ```
    <apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="FirstController" recordSetVar="listRecs" 
        action="{!send}">
        Emails are being sent!
        <script> window.history.back();
        </script>
    </apex:page>
   ```
3. FirstController code: for simplified code, I have edited snippet for contacts with email as our priority is only related to contacts with no email.

   ```
    public with sharing class FirstController
    {
    public List<Contact> noEmail {get;set;} 
    public Contact contact;
    public List<Contact> allcontact {get; set;} 
    Id test;
    public Contact getAllContact() {
            return contact;
    }

    ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon; 
    ApexPages.StandardController setCon1; 
    public static Boolean err{get;set;}
    public FirstController(ApexPages.StandardController controller) 
    {

             setCon1 = controller;  
    } 
    public FirstController(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)
     {

             setCon = controller;  
    } 
     public PageReference cancel()
     {
            return null;
    }
    public FirstController() 
    {

    }
    public PageReference send()
     {
     noEmail = new List<Contact>();
      set<id> ids = new set<id>();

     for(Integer i=0;i<setCon.getSelected().size();i++){
                    ids.add(setCon.getSelected()[i].id); 
            }
             if(ids.size() == 0){
                    err = true;
                    return null;
            }

      List<Contact> allcontact = [select Email, Name, firstName , LastName from Contact where Id IN :ids];
      for(Contact current : allcontact)
            {
            system.debug(current);
                    if (current.Email!= null)
                    {
                    PageReference pdf =  Page.pdfTest;
                    pdf.getParameters().put('id',(String)current.id); 
                    system.debug('id is :'+current.id);
                              pdf.setRedirect(true);
               return pdf;
                    }
                    else //No email 
                    {
                    system.debug('in else current'+current );
              noEmail.add(current);
             // noEmail.add(current);
             system.debug('in else noemail'+noEmail );
                    }//e
            }        

    if(noEmail.size()>0 ) {
     PageReference pdf1 =  Page.NoEmailVF;

      pdf1.getParameters().put('Name', String.valueOf(noEmail)); 
              system.debug('pring noEmail' +noEmail); 
              pdf1.setRedirect(false);
               return pdf1;

      } 
            return null;


    }   
    }
   ```
4. NoEmailVF visual force page code

   ```
    <apex:page controller="FirstController">
    <b> Emails are not sent to below contacts :  

    <table border="1">
    <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
     </tr>

    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!allcontact}" rendered="true">
    <tr>
            <td>{!cx.name}</td>
    </tr>   
    </apex:repeat> 
    </table> 
    <p> Please note that emails are not sent to selected Donors only when 
    they did not make any donation for that year or if they do not have email address listed. </p> 
    <p>If you still wish to retrieve donations made in this year, then you may use "Hard Copy" button listed on the Donor record to have the data printed. </p>
    </b>
    <apex:form >
    <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Back" immediate="true"/>.        
    </apex:form>
    </apex:page>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

It's bit messy. I think I know why it doesn't work but I'm also going to give you few tips how to clean it up.

I don't think you need 2 separate pages. You could do it on 1 page. I'm not even sure what were you trying to accomplish. Should the user be moved to previous page (some listview button I guess? Wherever `history.back()` takes them). Or to `Page.NoEmailVF`. (and there's even `Page.pdfTest` thrown into the mix ;))

If you're sure you need multiple pages - here's how you can transfer "state" of the controller across pages. It should work automatically as long as they share same controller (or extension), no need to pass anything via url: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_wizard.htm

Your constructors don't do much. They save the references to standard(set)controller but they don't run any queries. Contacts aren't queried until the `send()` method.

You're hoping to pass the `noEmail` parameter with `String.valueOf(List<Contact>)`. It's... uh.. it probably does something but after redirect you don't read anything. The `NoEmailVF` page has just `<apex:page controller=...` (not an extension) so the `FirstController()` (the one without any parameters) is called. And it has empty body! It completely ignores what was passed via url. It probably could read what you passed using `ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name')` but then honestly no idea what you can do to create real list of contacts out of such string. Messy. You probably could do some `JSON.serialize` and then `deserialize` but I don't like the whole idea.

And last but not least - calling page `action` is evil, unexpected for the user and against salesforce security best practices. Pls check my old answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/28853/799

So...

What a random internet stranger thinks you need:

1. 1 VF page. With only 1 constructor, the one that takes StandardSetController.
2. In the constructor inspect the `ssc.getSelected()` and query `SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :ssc.getSelected() AND Email = null`. Save the results of the query into `public contactsWithoutEmail {get; private set;}`
3. Do NOT have the `action={!send}` unless you absolutely need it automated. it should be conscious user's decision to click some final "Do it!" button.
4. In the `send()` method query only these `SELECT Id, Name FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :ssc.getSelected() AND Email != null` and process them.
5. In visualforce - use `<apex:pageBlockTable>`, `<apex:dataTable>` or similar to display `contactsWithoutEmail`. No need to hand-craft the html.
6. And I recommend making `send` a normal `apex:commandButton`, not `action`